# How to access one class to a another c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello everyone.

I am creating a website. In this website I add three folders:

1. Entities
2. Business logic
3. Data access logic

Now I wanna to access entities folder class functions into business logic folder class.

But when I try to add namespace of that class into my another class, it does not show the names of classes (no intelligence).

Here is my code of Entity class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for State
/// </summary>
namespace StateBLL
{
    public class State
    {
        #region private variable

        private string _State;

        #endregion


        #region Properties

        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return _State;
            }
            set
            {
                _State = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I Want to access this class (StateBLL) in another class. 
But I am not able to do this.
Please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: Is your problem that you cannot instantiate a StateBLL object in another class?

Comment: Have you added a reference from the class wanting to access this another classStateBLL

Comment: @NWard yes nward it is my problem

Comment: Try add something like "using BusinessLogic;" or whatever namespace your class implemented into.

Comment: its give me error that type or namespace could not be found

Comment: If you have the desired class implemented in the different assembly, you should add a refrence to that assembly (via Solution Explorer tool window)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i try this also but i did not find dll anywhere in project i build it also but not find it anywhere

Comment: @AzadChouhan you need to add reference, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to follow these steps

```
 right click BL-->Add reference-->Projects--> select entities project
```

now on the page where you want to instantiate your class add

```
using nameofyourentitylibrary; //replace nameofyourentitylibrary with the name of namespace
```

now you can instantiate

Comment: ya i try it but what i add there is nothing to add when i follow this steps its show me blank dialog box where my project is

Comment: you can browse the dll of your entity project as well. click browse in the add reference dialog and point it to the dll of your entity project

Comment: there is no dll anywhere in my project i build the project too

Comment: it will be in the bin directory of your entity project

Comment: bin directory is empty :(

Comment: build the entity project and you will get the dll there

Comment: i did that too but does not get anything

Comment: did you built the entity project? after building it. do a right click on your project and open in file explorer. Navigate to bin directory and browse the debug/release folder. you should be having the dll there

Answer (score 1):

Try to add reference of Entity Library to your Business Library and then add

```
using YourEntityLibray;
```

In your Business Library's Class

Answer (score 0):

First , remember entity make sure it should be public,so you can access anywhere
second ,build entity class and add reference to another class ,by right click on the folder add reference.
after that add namespace of entity then you can access your entity class